# When are traditional image processing methods preferable to machine learning and why?

Tags: machine-learning, comparison, computer-vision, image-processing

By traditional image processing I understand, e. g. using filters to improve the image, extracting edges and then classifying objects using template matching.

My current decision criteria are:

- large possible changes from picture to picture (e. g. lighting, angle of view, …) -> ML
- more complex problems (e. g. weld inspection) -> ML
- difficult generation of a labeled image dataset -> traditional approach
- traceability of the decisions -> traditional approach

Are there other general decision-making criteria that lead to a specific choice (especially if both variants would work for a given application)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.